# Method for checking admin is redirecting me to main page when trying to login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I created a method to check if a user is admin, so a component will render in the navbar, but after I did that, now when I try to login it always return me to the homepage.

```
let navigate = useNavigate();

  const userSignin = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  const checkAdmin = () => {
    if (userInfo) {
      if (userInfo.user) {
        return userInfo.user.isAdmin;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!checkAdmin()) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [userInfo]]);
```

I have the following components that depends on the flags:

```
{checkAdmin() && (
            <NavbarItem
              component='li'
              onMouseEnter={() => setTopMenuIndex(4)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setTopMenuIndex(-1)}
            >
              <Box
                style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}
                component='a'
                {...{ href: "/createItem" }}
              >
                {topMenuIndex === 4 && <Tippy topMenuIndex={topMenuIndex} />}
                Admin Dashboard
              </Box>
            </NavbarItem>
          )}

{userInfo ? (
            <Box
              onMouseEnter={() => setTopMenuIndex(3)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setTopMenuIndex(-1)}
              ml='24px'
            >
              <li>
                <IconLink component='a' {...{ href: "/account" }}>
                  <AccountCircleOutlined style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
                </IconLink>
                {topMenuIndex === 3 && <Tippy topMenuIndex={topMenuIndex} />}
              </li>
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <NavbarItem
              active={location.pathname === "/sign-in" ? 1 : 0}
              component='li'
            >
              <Box
                style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}
                component='a'
                {...{ href: "/sign-in" }}
              >
                Sign In
              </Box>
            </NavbarItem>
          )}
```

My question is how can I solve the problem so I can login normally, but if you aren't logged in you won't be able to access the route for the admin stuff.

In userAction.js:

```
export const signin = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_SIGNIN_REQUEST, payload: { email, password } });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3030/v1/user/login", {
      email,
      password,
    });
    dispatch({ type: USER_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_SIGNIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

In userReducer.js:

```
export const userSigninReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_SIGNIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_SIGNIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_SIGNOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In store.js:

```
const initialState = {
  userSignin: {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
      : null,
    resetInfo: localStorage.getItem("resetInfo")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resetInfo"))
      : null,
    verificationInfo: localStorage.getItem("verificationInfo")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("verificationInfo"))
      : null,
  },
  itemCreate: {
    creationInfo: localStorage.getItem("creationInfo")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("creationInfo"))
      : null,
  },
};
```

The routes are declared like that:

```
<Router>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/sign-in' element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
 </Router>
```

This is just an example I have a lot more userActions and routes, I hope this is enough.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a protected route wrapper to handle the auth check and redirect? It seems that `userInfo` is falsey in your code, so the `navigate("/")` occurs.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, I'm sending through redux, only a flag for loading.

Comment: Do you have any code to share that is updating the `userSignin` state? Can you included all relevant code you are trying to get working together? I.e. Where you are logging in, the redux state slices/reducers, etc..? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, I will edit the post again with the other infos.

Comment: Where in this code you've shared is the logic for "trying to log in but get redirected to homepage"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I solve the problem so I can login normally, but if you aren't logged in you won't be able to access the route for the admin stuff.

So, your objective is:

- if the user who access your app is not login yet OR has login but not an admin, protect the route for admin by redirecting the user to "/", right?

First, as mentioned in the comment, you can create a protected route like this

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function ProtectRoute(props: ProtectRouteProps) {
  const userSignin = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  return userInfo?.user?.isAdmin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
}
```

Refer to https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

In short, `ProtectRoute` will render the child route (we will see the implementation later), which is the admin route, if the user is detected as an admin by checking the value of `userInfo?.user?.isAdmin`. Otherwise, users will be redirected to "/".

Then, implement the `ProtectRoute` in your route list.

```
<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
      <Routes>
       <Route path='/sign-in' element={<Login />} />
       <Route path='/admin-page' element={<ProtectRoute />}>
         <Route path='/admin-page' element={<AdminPage />} /> 
       </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </Layout>
</Router>
```

I don't know what is the content of your `<Layout>`, but if it is contain `<Suspense>` then you don't have to put `<Suspense>` that I put under your `<Layout>`.

Comment: The problem right now is that the ProtectRouteProps is not found.

Comment: @Razmi its just an interface. I'm using typescript. Just create one or omit it if you are using JS