# Nested routing using protected routes is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

earlier I posted a similar question: [Method for checking admin is redirecting me to main page when trying to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314788/method-for-checking-admin-is-redirecting-me-to-main-page-when-trying-to-login)

I tried to implement the protected route, inside a protectRoute.tsx:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router";
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector } from "react-redux";

interface ProtectRouteProps {}

export default function ProtectRoute(props: ProtectRouteProps) {
  const userSignin = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  return userInfo?.user?.isAdmin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' />;
}
```

I don't really know what ProtectRouteProps is and what I should put in it. Also in the routing part I did like he told me:

```
<Route path='/createItem' element={<ProtectRoute />} />
<Route path='/createItem' element={<CreateItem />} />
```

The problem now is that can't access CreateItem because is going on the ProtectRoute page that is an empty one. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't really know what ProtectRouteProps is and what I should put in it.

There are no props. This is clear by the usage:

```
<Route path='/createItem' element={<ProtectRoute />} />
```

No props are passed to `ProtectRoute`. You can drop the props object:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router";
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function ProtectRoute() {
  const userSignin = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  return userInfo?.user?.isAdmin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' replace />;
}
```

> The problem now is that can't access CreateItem because is going on
> the ProtectRoute page that is an empty one. What should i do?

"Auth" routes are what are called [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). They apply some logic, perhaps some styled layout CSS, and render an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. The nested `Route` components use the `path` prop for route matching.

Example:

```
<Route element={<ProtectRoute />}>
  <Route path='/createItem' element={<CreateItem />} />
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
```

Comment: It finally worked, now I understood what I did wrong, I wasn't closing the <Route element={<ProtectRoute />}> tag

Comment: @Razmi Well, it was *technically* closed (*self-closed*), which is valid JSX.... it just wasn't wrapping the route/routes you wanted to protect. This was a much better follow-on question from your initial post, BTW. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login name="Login Page"></Login>}></Route>
    <Route element={<Protected/>}> 
    <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/> }></Route>
    <Route exact path='/Content' element={<Content />}></Route>
    </Route>

   <Route path='*' element={<Login/>} ></Route>
  </Routes>
```

Create Protected.js

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

   const useAuth = ()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem("isLogged")){
    const user = {loggedIN :true};
    return user && user.loggedIN
    }else{
    const user = {loggedIN :false};
    return user && user.loggedIN
   }

 }

 const Protected = () => {
 const isAuth = useAuth();
 return isAuth ? <Outlet/>:<Navigate to={"/login"}/>
 }

export default Protected
```